# Can we add view to the child of a layout?

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout in my xml.

On runtime i add one image view of fill parent in this linear layout. Now i want to add one button over this imageview. Is this possible to add this button at center of this image view ? can we add view in child of any other view.

Please suggest me what should i do for this.

Comment: FrameLayout can have multiple views stacked over each other

Comment: sir i am using simple xml in my code. only linear layout is there. At run time first i create image view, which fill this linear layout. Now i want to add a button on center of this image view. Please suggest me what should i do for this. I have very big application. And this is the concept in which i stuck...

Comment: `RelativeLayout` can be also helpful

Comment: Have you tried addView(View child, int index) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
     <Button android:id="@_id/the_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When you want to make the button visible:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.the_button);
b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```